# mixed ANOVA alterantive for inhomogeneity of variances in SPSS

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity

I am trying to compute a mixed ANOVA with

1. one within-subjects factor (two different types of stimulus categories) and
2. one between-subjects factors (three participant groups).

My problem is that the three groups vary in size (group 1 and 2 each have 25 participants and group 3 has 50 participants).Different group sizes are not a problem per se. But testing the ANOVA assumptions indicated that the homogeneity of variances.

I don't think there is an SPSS alternative to a mixed design ANOVA, judging buy other posts I have read? Are there any other options I could try? Transforming the data or any other ideas?

Any ideas are welcome and would help!

Best,
Spica